# Difference between OPC UA and REST Web-Service

Tags: web-services, rest, opc, opc-ua

I want to ask, what is the difference between OPC UA and REST Web-Service.

Comment: In very terse terms OPC-DA (Classic) was a windows only protocol and heavily builds upon COM/DCOM as protocols. It is one of the most popular M2M protocols still very prevalent in the industry. OPC supported both DA and more recently UA based access to information. DA relied heavily on COM/DCOM and UA provided more options in terms of providing HTTP based connectivity through SOAP based services. REST is a "relatively" newer paradigm of stateless services that is quite popular. It can use HTTP as transport of information and is different from WSDL based SOAP/HTTP services

Comment: OPC UA is not based on HTTP and SOAP. That is still an option, but in practice all communication is done through an optimised binary protocol. In general, OPC UA defines different transport protocols, security policies and information models, so it is much more higher level than REST. REST could be used as the transport protocol of OPC UA.

Comment: A little late for this post but here is a link to a OPC Rest API i developed using OpenOpc: https://github.com/matzpersson/opc-rest-api

Comment: I don't think OPC UA has anything to do with the method of communications.  It is an architectural standard.  In theory you can use any communication method to connect things.  They started off by also supporting SOAP and raw binary TCP as standards, but they may add new supported ones in the future, and there is absolutely no reason why somebody cannot develop their own communications to use with OPC UA, as long as both server and client understand it.  I, for one, would really like to see WebSocket.

Comment: So this question is like, you have two balls connected to each other by a string; what is the difference between the balls and the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am unable to comment (below 50 points) so small correction to Ramachandran G A statement "OPC-UA was a windows only protocol" -- it was OPC classic. The point with OPC UA is it is multi language, platform independent.

As for the question, you compare two different things in sense REST WS is way more general, it is about how the data are exchanged in broad sense. OPC UA brings "logic" to data exchange -- alarms, events, historic data, filtering, subscription, etc.

Answer (score 0):

### [2020 Update] You can convert OPC UA to REST using Open-Plant (FREE)

OPC UA is a standard that also includes the OPC-UA TCP protocol, while REST is an architectural style that can leverage standards. But you can convert OPC UA to REST API using Open-Plant. Open-Plant is a free Industrial IOT Platform. Just download and install it. Once installed there will be a component called OpenPlantOPC which will allow one to access OPC UA via REST API. There should be a REST API guide somewhere in their website

https://www.open-plant.com

Comment: broken link; try here maybe: https://github.com/Open-Plant/OpenPlantOPC